# json: cannot unmarshal number 5088060241 into struct of type int

Tags: json, go, integer, terraform

I'm working on a Terraform project using the OVH provider, when the record is created, the provider is unable to fetch the ID of the record and trigger this error :
`cannot unmarshal number 5088060240 into Go struct field OvhDomainZoneRecord.id of type int`

I opened an issue on the github repository but still waiting for an answer.
I would like to correct the problem by myself but i'm not a Go developper and i canno't find any related error.

The struct of OvhDomainZoneRecord :

```
type OvhDomainZoneRecord struct {
    Id        int    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Zone      string `json:"zone,omitempty"`
    Target    string `json:"target"`
    Ttl       int    `json:"ttl,omitempty"`
    FieldType string `json:"fieldType"`
    SubDomain string `json:"subDomain,omitempty"`
}
```

The related file :
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-ovh/blob/master/ovh/resource_ovh_domain_zone_record.go

Comment: Because this: https://play.golang.com/p/s7QA5O0rsh3. Use `int64` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size of `int` is either 32 or 64 bit depending on the target architecture you compile to and run on. Your input `5088060240` is bigger than the max value of a 32-bit integer (which is `2147483647`), so if your `int` is 32-bit, you get this error.

Easiest fix is to use `int64`. See this example:

```
var i int32
fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte("5088060240"), &i))

var j int64
fmt.Println(json.Unmarshal([]byte("5088060240"), &j))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/n_0r-caTWuq)):

```
json: cannot unmarshal number 5088060240 into Go value of type int32
<nil>
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer, i'll fork the project and change it

Comment: @MartinPaucot Or use 64-bit target (if that's an option for you), but yes, if you may get numbers this big, it's better to be explicit about the integer size.

Comment: I will use int64, it's a temporary change. As I said, I really do not know Go. It's just for waiting a real fix